# Linq Expression to select items based on list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with parentId field and childId field.I have to select the childId field data based on a list of parentId  comparing with parentId field values.

**here is the sample:**

```
List<int> parents=new list(){1,2,4};
```

Table :

```
          parentId    childId
            1            3
            5            5
            2            4
            4            7
```

how can i select the childId using linq expression

Answer (score 0):

```
var childId = yourTable.Where(m => parents.Contains(m.parentId)).Select(m => m.childId).ToList()
```

Comment: I want to map the list with table and from that selection fetch the childid.

Comment: @BruceWayne so there would be list of patientId?

Comment: @BruceWayne Updated for list of parents

Answer (score 0):

```
var childId = child.Where(x => parents.Contains(x.parentId)).Select(x => x.childId).ToList();
```